# How to overcome incognito challenges in Cypress test automation tool

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, browser-automation

We have a situation where we are planning to port the test from Selenium to Cypress due to various technical reasons.
Our application is quite complex when it comes to cookies and caches. As a result, the tests in Selenium are run always in incognito mode. We launch a browser in incognito mode run the test and dispose the browser.

For the POC, I have taken 5 test cases and automated it. When I run each of the test in silos ( by commenting out the remaining tests in the test suite ) all looks good and GREEN.

But when I run all the tests in a suite , the first test passes and all the remaining tests fails.

I am very sure this is because of the cache ( or some info ) which is stored in the browser after every test.

Not sure how to resolve this using Cypress.

I tried the following

```
beforeEach('Before Each Block',function(){
      cy.clearLocalStorage()
      cy.clearCookies()
       cy.reload(true);
    })
```

Is there some command in cypress which deletes every trace and launches a new fresh browser state which does not have traces of the previous tests for the smooth run of the tests.
Thanks very much for your help on this.

Comment: Hi @Timothy Rajan There is a Global config in cypress called `numTestsKeptInMemory` which says - The number of tests for which snapshots and command data are kept in memory. Reduce this number if you are experiencing high memory consumption in your browser during a test run. Put it as 0  `numTestsKeptInMemory: 0` in your cypress.json file and give it a try. it might solve your issue. You can check the Global configs from here - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Global

Comment: @AlapanDas - Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Let me try this now

Comment: @AlapanDas - Thanks a lot. Wish to get back to you with a solution. Unfortunately, I was not able to come up with an solution. The immediate solution is to have one test in one spec file. Thanks again for your help on this.

Answer (score -2):

can you try this in the `beforeEach()` Hook,

```js
cy.exec('npm cache clear --force')
```

Comment: Please provide more information. This is not a good answer, this should be a comment asking for more information.